# Move Linux tmp folders

Tags: linux-mint, zfs, temporary-files

I have Mint 19 installed on a fairly old machine, where the performance isnt great.  I was able to move the swap partition to a ZFS pool with these [instructions](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-use-a-zvol-as-a-swap-device).  However, I want to move the `/tmp` and `/var/temp` to the ZFS pool for increased disk speed, as well.  However, I cant seem to find decent instructions on how to do that.  How should I go about moving those two folders into a ZFS pool?

Comment: [moving only some directories / filesystems to ZFS datasets](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/405492)

Answer (score 1):

*Replace `rpool` with your ZFS pool name in the instructions below.*

## Move `/tmp` to ZFS

1. Move your existing `/tmp` directory somewhere else:

   ```
   mv /tmp /tmp2
   ```
2. Create a ZFS file system for `/tmp`.  Note that the `mountpoint` property should be `legacy` due to an outstanding [race condition bug mentioned in the ZFS on Linux wiki](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS#step-4-system-configuration) <sup>[[Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180906233810/https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-18.04-Root-on-ZFS#step-4-system-configuration), step 4.11]</sup>.

   ```
   zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy rpool/tmp
   ```
3. Copy the contents of your old `/tmp` folder to the new one:

   ```
   rsync -avHXShPs /tmp2/ /tmp/
   ```
4. Verify that the contents copied over correctly before deleting the old `/tmp` folder:

   ```
   rm -rfv /tmp2
   ```
5. Add the new `/tmp` folder to `/etc/fstab` so that it is mounted on boot:

   ```
   echo "rpool/tmp /tmp zfs defaults 0 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab
   ```

## Move `/var/tmp` to ZFS

Basically the same instructions apply.

1. ```
   mv /var/tmp /var/tmp2
   ```
2. ```
   zfs create -o mountpoint=none   rpool/var
   zfs create -o mountpoint=legacy rpool/var/tmp
   ```
3. ```
   rsync -avHXShPs /var/tmp2/ /var/tmp/
   ```
4. ```
   rm -rfv /var/tmp2
   ```
5. ```
   echo "rpool/var/tmp /var/tmp zfs defaults 0 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab
   ```